# How to send an Zend Form with Dojo and XHR by pressing Enter

Tags: forms, zend-framework, dojo, xmlhttprequest, enter

**First**, the things I use:
I am using Dojo 1.6 and Zend Framework 1.11.5 - and no, I will not update now.

**Second**, my situation:
I have a Zend_Form with enabled Zend_Dojo support.
I am creating the formular in my action controller and give it to the view, who renders perfectly. The formular calls an javascript function, which puts variables into an URL, which is used to update a content pane.

**Third**, my problem:
The formular is not sent when pressing [ENTER], only on click of the button.

**Fourth**, my code:
Comments are left out, code is made simpler and nicer to read. Some parts are missing.

Here is a part of my Zend_Form/_Dojo:

*/application/forms/CommunityDeviceFinderForm.php*

```
class CommunityDeviceFinderForm extends Zend_Form {

public function init(){
    Zend_Dojo::enableForm($this);

    $this->setMethod('post');
    $this->setAttribs(array(
        'name' => 'findDeviceForm'
    ));
}

public function createElements(){
    // some $this->addElement here

    $this->addElement(
        'Button',
        'submitDeviceSearch',
        array(
            'label'    => tr_('Search'),
            'required' => false,
            'ignore'   => true,
            'onClick'  => 'findDevice()'  // the called javascript function
        )
    );
```

I leave out my controller. It's just creating the formular and giving it to the view  (as "$deviceSearchForm") anyways.

My view script. Also shortened a lot:

*/application/modules/default/views/scripts/default/de/community/device-finder.phtml*

```
<script>
    function findDevice(){
        var formular = dijit.byId('<?=$this->deviceSearchForm->getAttrib('name')?>');

        if(formular.isValid()){
            // collecting form vars and creating an URL
            // then refreshing a content pane with the created URL
        } else {
            // error shown
        }
    }
</script>

<!-- some html -->

        <?=$this->deviceSearchForm?>

<!-- some more html -->
```

I guess - or know - the problem is the "Button" is no "SubmitButton". But I do not want a page refresh. How do I connect something like an onSubmit to the formular? Listening to the event and preventing default actions. Instead calling my findDevice() js-function.

I can not listen to the keystroke himself, because the almost exact formular is right beside it again, which shall work for its own.

I would love something like: Adding an attribute namend "onSubmit" to the formular attributes array, which links to the js-function findDevice().

And sorry for my bad english :(

Thanks a lot!
-Philipp

Comment: Even if you're capable of getting the submit event without submit button, you still have a problem. Some browsers (Safari is one of them) do not allow submit events without a valid submit button in your form.

Comment: Thank you! Okay, so I replace the button with a submit button - which is okay, as long as i can prevent the submit event from refreshing the page. Instead it has to call the findDevice() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found with a friend of mine - the above answer. This is the full code now.

Add "*findDevice(); return false;*" as "*onSubmit*" to the attributes of the zend formular.
The function findDevice() is called then. The "return false;" is preventing it from doing it's usual stuff, like the refresh.

Also, there is no need to overwrite the onClick event of the submit button anymore.

So here is the code. The view script stayed untouched.

*/application/forms/CommunityDeviceFinderForm.php*

```
class CommunityDeviceFinderForm extends Zend_Form {

    public function init(){
        Zend_Dojo::enableForm($this);

        $this->setMethod('get')
             ->setAttribs(array('name'     => 'findDeviceForm',
                                'onSubmit' => 'findDevice(); return false;'));
    }

    public function createElements(){

        // [...]

        $this->addElement(
            'SubmitButton',
            'submitDeviceSearch',
            array('label'    => tr_('Search'),
                  'required' => false,
                  'ignore'   => true));

        // [...]
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try to set a onsubmit event to your form like this:

```
$this->setAttribs(array(
    'name' => 'findDeviceForm',
    'onSubmit' => 'findDevice(); return false;'
));
```

Then your findDevice() function is called on submit and the "return false;" part prevents the actual submit/page refresh.